# How do I add a $\square$ at the end of a paragraph and align it to the right, as if it were the end of proof (not via \begin{proof} !)

Tags: symbols

How do I add a \square  (or anything else) at the end of a paragraph and align it to the right as if it is the end of proof (without \begin{proof} at the beginning). I don't want to see the "proof" at the beginning.

And at the same time, I only need a local/temporary change. I don't want to change the "proof" environment at the beginning. I still want to use \begin{proof} normally in other places

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just declare `\qed` at the end of the paragraph, which is essentially what `\end{proof}` does automatically (with some more bells and whistles you don't need for your situation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

A paragraph with a QED symbol at the far end. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines.\qed

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can locally change the QED symbol. I suggest a special command for the task you want (a triangle instead of the square).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\triangleqed}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\triangle}}%
  \qed
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

A paragraph with a QED symbol at the far end. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines.\qed

A paragraph with a QED symbol at the far end. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines.\triangleqed

A paragraph with a QED symbol at the far end. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines. Let's go on with
nonsense words just to get a few lines.\qed

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and what is the easiest way to replay \qed with other symbols like $\triangle$ temporally that still do the same job (pushed to the end of a line)?

Comment: @NoOne I added a possible way.

Comment: @NoOne You should edit the question to also reflect the added requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[2]
  \unskip\nobreak\hfill $\square$

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

This shows how output has been produced:
[image]

Comment: You perhaps meant not to have a blank line before `\hfill$\square$`. However, this doesn't guarantee that the square falls at the end of the line. And the symbol used by `amsthm` is not `$\square$`.

Comment: Yes, e.g. with `\lipsum[8]` the square would go to the start of the next line.